# Java - Scanner : reading line of record separated by Pipe | as delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to read a text file where fields data are  separated by delimiter | (pipe symbol).

**But some unexpected happened :**

Here is my code :

```
doScannerTest ("Y~2011~GT~Nepal~Ganesh~Tiwari~N", "~");
doScannerTest("Y|2011|GT|Nepal|Ganesh|Tiwari|N", "|");

private static void doScannerTest(String recordLine, String delim) {
    java.util.Scanner lineScanner = new java.util.Scanner(recordLine);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(delim);
    while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(lineScanner.next());
    }
}
```

The delim ~ works fine but | prints all characters in recordLine.

Why the record with delim | is not working ? I cannot change the framework code(which uses Scanner) and use String Split.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the pipe character is a reserved regex character, you will need to escape it.
for example you need to use

```
\\|
```

putting that in your code gives the below output

- Y
- 2011
- GT
- Nepal
- Ganesh
- Tiwari
- N

Comment: OH. i got it. used "[|\\*]" instead of |. and problem got solved.. thanks